# iOS: POST where JSON is just one argument of many

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, post

I have successfully used JSON as arguments to a POST webservices in my apps by making the data representation of the JSON the HTTP body:

```
    //Prep
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:<my JSON> options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *apiString = <the webservice>;

    //POST
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    //Go
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    queryResultData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Which works great.

The trouble is, this works for a webservice which is expecting a single JSON argument as the http body.

**How can I include JSON as one of many arguments**, the way you can use the data encoding of @"arg1=val1&arg2=val2".

For example: image you have a webservice expecting something like

```
    http://mysite.com/api/v1/route/test?data={json:%22true%22}&other=abcdefg
```

Which must be submitted as a POST.

This, interestingly, has a JSON dictionary as only one argument of many, and not in the body at that.  I can't figure out how to add these arguments to the post.

### EDIT

Here's the same concept in php.  How do you do this in Cocoa?

```
$data = array('x' => 1, 'name => 'fred');

$json = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json_data' => $json));
 -- or --
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'something=whatever&json_data='.$json);
```